# Is it possible to write to a python frame object as returned by sys._getframe() from python code running within the interpreter?

Tags: python, introspection, frame, sys

Apropos of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541329/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-construct-a-python-stack-frame-and-start-execu), there is a bit of scaffolding within the interpreter to inspect frame objects, which can be retrieved by `sys._getframe()`.  The frame objects appear to be read only, but I can't find anything obvious in the docs that explicitly states this.  Can someone confirm whether these objects are writeable (in some way) or read only?

```
import sys

def foobar():
    xx='foo'
    ff = sys._getframe()
    ff.f_locals['xx'] = 'bar'
    print xx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foobar()
```

This prints out '`foo`' when run but the post below demonstrates the variable being writable when run from the current frame in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From CPython source, `Objects/frameobject.c`:

```c
static PyMemberDef frame_memberlist[] = {
    {"f_back",      T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_back),    RO},
    {"f_code",      T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_code),    RO},
    {"f_builtins",  T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_builtins),RO},
    {"f_globals",   T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_globals), RO},
    {"f_lasti",     T_INT,          OFF(f_lasti),   RO},
    {"f_exc_type",  T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_exc_type)},
    {"f_exc_value", T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_exc_value)},
    {"f_exc_traceback", T_OBJECT,   OFF(f_exc_traceback)},
    {NULL}    /* Sentinel */
};
...
static PyGetSetDef frame_getsetlist[] = {
    {"f_locals",    (getter)frame_getlocals, NULL, NULL},
    {"f_lineno",    (getter)frame_getlineno,
                    (setter)frame_setlineno, NULL},
    {"f_trace",     (getter)frame_gettrace, (setter)frame_settrace, NULL},
    {"f_restricted",(getter)frame_getrestricted,NULL, NULL},
    {0}
};
```

For the `PyMemberDef`, the flags `RO` or `READONLY` means it's attributes are read-only. For the `PyGetSetDef`, if it only has a getter, it's read only. This means all attributes but `f_exc_type`, `f_exc_value`, `f_exc_traceback` and `f_trace` are read-only after creation. This is also mentioned in the docs, under [Data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-1767).

The objects referred to by the attributes is not necessarily read-only. You could do this:

```
>>> f = sys._getframe()
>>> f.f_locals['foo'] = 3
>>> foo
3
>>>
```

Though this works in the interpreter, it fails inside functions. The execution engine uses a separate array for local variables (`f_fastlocals`), which is merged into `f_locals` on access, but the converse is not true.

```
>>> def foo():
...   x = 3
...   f = sys._getframe()
...   print f.f_locals['x']
...   x = 4
...   print f.f_locals['x']
...   d = f.f_locals
...   x = 5
...   print d['x']
...   f.f_locals
...   print d['x']
...
>>> foo()
3
4
4
5
>>>
```

On the global frame, `f_local` refers to `f_globals`, which makes this trick work in the interpreter. Modifying `f_globals` works, but affects the whole module.

Comment: Interesting.  This seems to be the behaviour on an interactive shell, but f_locals seems to be read only on a script.  See my expanded question - this code snippet run in an interpreter appears to be read only.

Answer (score 1):

The f_locals['foo'] example by NXC works because the code is in module scope. In that case, f_locals is f_globals, and f_globals is both modifiable and modifications are reflected in the module.

Inside of function scope, locals() and f_locals are writable, but "[changes may not affect the values of local variables used by the interpreter]." [1](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) It's an implementation choice. In CPython there's a optimized bytecode for local variables, LOAD_FAST. In Python, local variables are (almost always) known once the function is defined, and CPython uses an index lookup to get the variable value, rather than a dictionary lookup.

In theory the dictionary lookup could proxy that table, but that's a lot of work for little gain.

The exceptions to "local variables are known" are if the function uses an exec statement, and the deprecated case of "from module import *". The generated byte code is different, and slower, for these cases.