# Retrieving/Printing execution context

Tags: python

EDIT: This question has been solved with help from apphacker and ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells. I have updated the code to reflect the solution I will be using.

I am currently writing a swarm intelligence simulator and looking to give the user an easy way to debug their algorithms. Among other outputs, I feel it would be beneficial to give the user a printout of the execution context at the beginning of each step in the algorithm.

The following code achieves what I was needing.

```
import inspect

def print_current_execution_context():
    frame=inspect.currentframe().f_back #get caller frame
    print frame.f_locals #print locals of caller

class TheClass(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def thefunction(self,a,b):
        c=a+b
        print_current_execution_context()


C=TheClass(2)
C.thefunction(1,2)
```

This gives the expected output of:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'self': <__main__.TheClass object at 0xb7d2214c>}
```

Thank you to apphacker and ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells who pointed me towards this answer

Comment: There is no need to tag the title since tags are officially supported. As much attention [Python] in the title might bring to your question, it doesn't measure up the big yellow background I get when you actually use 'python' as a tag.

Comment: Don't edit the question to say "solved"  -- Accept the answer that solved it.  Or post your own answer.

Comment: In future I will, however the edit simply replaced #???? with 2 lines that realised the function, so it was not a drastic change.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
class TheClass(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def thefunction(self,a,b):
        c=a+b
        print locals()


C=TheClass(2)
C.thefunction(1,2)
```

Comment: That works well thanks. Is there a way to embed this within another function? As there are other actions that occur at the end of each iteration and it would be nice to group them within a single function.

I realise that the locals() could be passed into the function, however this is not optimal.

Comment: You could use a closure and a dictionary higher in scope that you update with values from a call to locals during each iteration, but if passing locals() into the function isn't optimal, I doubt a closure would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__locals__` to get the local execution context.  See [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541329/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-construct-a-python-stack-frame-and-start-execu) for some discussion that may also be pertinent.

Comment: Thanks, the linked thread sounds quite similar to what I was hoping to accomplish. I'll investigate grabbing `__locals__` from the stack frames and edit my question to report on the findings. Thanks, Mike